# Plugin Intellij - Show command in IDE terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I am developing a plugin in intellij to be used in pycharm. In my plugin I create a String that represents a command to be executed when I press a button. My problem is that I need to paste the command I created in the IDE terminal (it has the environment i need to execute the command) but I can't do that. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please check the similar question and the answer at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360005329339-Execute-command-in-the-terminal-from-plugin-action. Does it help?

Comment: Thanks for your help. You pointed me in the right direction.